# use NVL (),() AS COLUMN IN HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql, case-when, nvl

I have to translate my PL/SQL data into HIVE with main format:

`NVL(SELECT FROM (SELECT)),(SELECT FROM (SELECT)) AS EXPI_DATE`

My raw data looks like this :

```
NVL(
(SELECT MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EF_DATE
    FROM (SELECT C,
                  S,
                  DATE_TIME FROM(SELECT C,
                                      S,
                                      DATE_TIME,
                                      CASE
                                      WHEN lead over ( order by ) IS NULL
                                        THEN 'Y'
                                        ELSE 'N'
                                      END AS flag
                                        FROM table_1 
                            )aihiscur
          WHERE flag = 'Y') Z
          AND Z.DATE_TIME                                        > A.DATE_TIME
),
(SELECT
      MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EF_DATE
        FROM (SELECT  C,
                      S,
                      DATE_TIME 
                        FROM (SELECT C,
                          S,
                          DATE_TIME,
                                      CASE
                                      WHEN lead over ( order by ) IS NULL
                                        THEN 'Y'
                                        ELSE 'N'
                                      END AS flag
                          FROM table_2
                              )aicuri
                WHERE flag = 'Y') Z
      WHERE CU_CODE = A.cR_CODE 
      AND Z.DATE_TIME     > A.DATE_TIME
      )aicurin 
) AS EXPI_DATE
```

My questions is:

1. What is the efficient way to do this since hive forbid the use of NVL(),()

All the help and ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: use `WITH` clause to create two different CTE and then use them in SELECT. You can try `ifnull` instead of NVL but it will not work the way you are writing SQL.

Comment: what do you mean by this 'with clause to create two different CTE'?

Answer (score 0):

Does `COALESCE` work for you in this case?

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT MIN(DATE_TIME) FROM (SELECT ...)),
    (SELECT MIN(DATE_TIME) FROM (SELECT ...))
) AS EXPI_DATE
```

Comment: I was trying, but dont get the expected result.

Comment: @thecardcaptor what's the result that you got, and what's the result that you expected?

Comment: hoah, it's you again! haha should we move to private? so., in pl/sql (oracle), the NVL stands like this : https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php Im working in hue. I expected the same results as oracle.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225887/discussion-between-mck-and-thecardcaptor